# Eliminating duplicate combinations from result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select result like this:

```
from_loc    | to_loc   |
-------------------------
 A          |  B
------------------------
 B          |  C
------------------------
 B          |  A
------------------------
```

How can I eliminate duplicates from the table which means occurrence of **A to B** and **B to A** means duplicate.

I'm trying to create result like this, after trying couple of ways I couldn't solve this problem...

```
from_loc    | to_loc   |
-------------------------
 A          |  B
------------------------
 B          |  C
------------------------
```

Can anyone give me some hint or reference how can I achieve this kind of result?

Comment: Post your current SQL query

Comment: Hi Shai, my query is really big and I just put here very simplified scenario for sake of making it understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't tested this solution but it could have a better performance (less logical reads):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    from_loc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    to_loc   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @MyTable (from_loc, to_loc) VALUES  ('A', 'B');
INSERT  @MyTable (from_loc, to_loc) VALUES  ('B', 'C');
INSERT  @MyTable (from_loc, to_loc) VALUES  ('B', 'A');

SELECT  DISTINCT src.from_loc_new, src.to_loc_new
FROM
(
SELECT  CASE WHEN x.from_loc <= x.to_loc THEN x.from_loc ELSE x.to_loc END AS from_loc_new,
        CASE WHEN x.from_loc <= x.to_loc THEN x.to_loc ELSE x.from_loc END AS to_loc_new
FROM    @MyTable x
) src
-- You could also test these query hints to see if there is a better performance
-- OPTION (HASH GROUP) 
-- or 
-- OPTION (ORDER GROUP);
```

Comment: What will happened if there's only a record with value ('D', 'C')??? This SQL will reverse it into ('C', 'D'), right? Is this what you want?

Comment: @OchiWansa: 2 & 3) Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with this `CASE` in `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS( 
  SELECT from_loc, to_loc, 
         rn = row_Number() Over (Partition By  CASE WHEN from_loc > to_loc
                                    Then to_loc + '|' + from_loc 
                                    Else from_loc + '|' + to_loc END
                                 Order By from_loc, to_loc)
  FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT from_loc, to_loc FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8aee75/15/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try `DISTINCT` then `NOT EXISTS` , like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_loc, to_loc
FROM TableName A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT from_loc, to_loc
  FROM TableName B
  WHERE A.from_loc = B.to_loc
  AND A.to_loc = B.from_loc
 )
```

The `DISTINCT` will eliminate duplicate `from_loc-->from_loc` and `to_loc--->to_loc`
while `NOT EXISTS` will eliminate duplicate `from_loc-->to_loc` and `to_loc-->from_loc`.

Comment: This will get rid of both copies of the duplicate, i.e. removes `A | B` **and** `B | A`. The question needs one of these two rows to remain

Answer (score 0):

Assume your original SQL is:

```
SELECT from_loc, to_loc FROM route;
```

Use it twice as subqueries which joined together with `LEFT JOIN`. After that, select distinctly the needed fields using `IF`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  IF (y.from_loc IS NULL, x.from_loc,
    IF(x.from_loc < x.to_loc, x.from_loc, x.to_loc)) AS from_loc,
  IF (y.from_loc IS NULL, x.to_loc,
    IF(x.from_loc > x.to_loc, x.from_loc, x.to_loc)) AS to_loc
FROM (
) AS x
  SELECT from_loc, to_loc FROM route
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT from_loc, to_loc FROM route
) AS y
ON x.from_loc = y.to_loc AND x.to_loc = y.from_loc;
```

For demo, I use the following SQL to create the sample data in your question:

```
SELECT "A" AS from_loc, "B" AS to_loc
UNION SELECT "B", "C"
UNION SELECT "B", "A";
```

Try this on your MySQL client application:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  IF (y.from_loc IS NULL, x.from_loc,
    IF(x.from_loc < x.to_loc, x.from_loc, x.to_loc)) AS from_loc,
  IF (y.from_loc IS NULL, x.to_loc,
    IF(x.from_loc > x.to_loc, x.from_loc, x.to_loc)) AS to_loc
FROM (
) AS x
  SELECT "A" AS from_loc, "B" AS to_loc
  UNION SELECT "B", "C"
  UNION SELECT "B", "A"
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT "A" AS from_loc, "B" AS to_loc
  UNION SELECT "B", "C"
  UNION SELECT "B", "A"
) AS y
ON x.from_loc = y.to_loc AND x.to_loc = y.from_loc;
```

I know this is not an efficient solution, but it just works!